# What is a CloudKit RecordID

Tags: cloudkit

While starting to work more with CloudKit I just realized that I don't actually know what a RecordID is...

I'm looking at the CloudKit dashboard right now, I see RecordTypes, RecordName etc, but I don't see RecordID.  The iOS Dev library mentions RecordID a lot, but never actually tells what it is or where to find it.

I guess I'm just dumb, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every record has a record Id, which is a [CKRecordID](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CloudKit/Reference/CKRecordID_class/index.html) instance, and the class has a `name` property. If you don't specify a name, new records will have a record Id with a name that is a GUID.

You can only fetch with record Id if you know it, and in most instances you will let Cloud Kit create on for you, and you won't store it locally, so you won't know it.

Every CKRecord has a bunch of metadata, which includes the record id. See the list [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CloudKit/Reference/CKRecord_class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014044-CH1-SW14).

Comment: Okay, so how do I know what the recordIDs for my records?

In the Dev Library it says the easiest way to fetch records is using the RecordID, but where and how do I get the recordID?

Comment: Ok, I was thinking the recordID was something that I should know.  So I won't worry about using the getRecordID type functions.
Thanks!

Comment: In some instances it can be useful to specify your own record name. For example, if there's only one config record, you can call it "config" so you can retrieve it by record id.

Answer (score 1):

Here a snapshot of the dashboard, your recognised it. You can either accept the recordIDs that CloudKit gives you or generate your own [although they must be unique within your database instance].  Here the screenshot

[image]

And here a small code snippet to show you how to create your own ID, using the same method I suspect CloudKit uses.

```
 let uniqueReference = NSUUID().UUIDString
 let uniqueRecordID = CKRecordID(recordName: uniqReference)
 let newRecord = CKRecord(recordType: "Collection", recordID:uniqueRecordID)
```